# Open setting menu On click with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have been trying to make a setting button which toggles my settings section On click, but no hope, if you can help me I would be thankful, Here is the HTML and JS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="apping.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <button id="toggler" style="font-size:24px">Settings <i class="fa fa-gear"></i></button>
<section>
   <h2> Dark Mode!</h2>
   <label class="switch">
    <input id="slider" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</section>
    <script src="app.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the Javascript

```
let slider = document.getElementById('slider');

let section = document.getElementById('section');

let toggler = document.getElementById('toggler');


toggler.addEventListener('click',function(){
    section.classList.toggle("opacity");
})
```

and this is the class i'm trying to toggle in css, is there something i'm missing?

```
.opacity {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any element with id `section`, assign an id="section" to your section tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was it necessary?

```js
let slider = document.getElementById('slider');

let section = document.getElementById('section');

let toggler = document.getElementById('toggler');


toggler.addEventListener('click',function(){
    section.classList.toggle("opacity");
})
```

```css
#section {
  opacity: 0;
}

.opacity {
  opacity: 1!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="apping.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <button id="toggler" style="font-size:24px">Settings <i class="fa fa-gear"></i></button>
<section id="section">
   <h2> Dark Mode!</h2>
   <label class="switch">
    <input id="slider" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</section>
    <script src="app.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes sorry i'm just a beginner programmer and i forgot such small things from time to time, thanks for reminding me about the ID :)

Comment: This is a normal moment when you forget or ignore something :) Always happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add **id="section"** to your section tag, and also you need to set the initial state of the section to `opacity: 0`.

```js
let slider = document.getElementById('slider');

let section = document.getElementById('section');

let toggler = document.getElementById('toggler');


toggler.addEventListener('click',function(){
    section.classList.toggle("opacity");
})
```

```css
#section {
  opacity: 0
}

#section.opacity {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="apping.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <button id="toggler" style="font-size:24px">Settings <i class="fa fa-gear"></i></button>
<section id="section">
   <h2> Dark Mode!</h2>
   <label class="switch">
    <input id="slider" type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
</section>
    <script src="app.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes sorry i'm just a beginner programmer and i forgot such small things from time to time, thanks for reminding me about the ID :)

Comment: It's totally fine, we all were beginners once :) 
If you find my answer useful, please mark it as accepted